# Access: Subform not editable

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I got assigned a task for a developer that is sick.

There's an access DB that needed some modifications.
It's made up of 2 DB's, one holding the data (lets call it back.mdb), and the other one as a forefront (let's call it front.mdb), linked to back.mdb and it holds the forms.

I made a few changes to the DB, and now a subform in one of the forms is no longer editable.

The thing is if i open the original front.mdb file, the subform works (it links to the same back.mdb file).

The source code does not have a reference to the subform, so it's not locked by code.

I even copied the subform from the original form, but it wont work.

Any ideas?

Update: Here's a screenshot of the subform:

[image: mybN6cP.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

It depends where you made the changes (Backend or Frontend?) and also depends what you mean by the form no longer being editable (Cannot be opened in design view or just can't edit the data in the form?) but the most likely answer is that you have changed something that has upset a query or relationship that the subform relies on. Without more information about what you actually changed, I can't suggest much else.

Comment: So, changes were made on the backend db, and on the forms in the front end db.

Comment: I would have said that my change broke the relationship, but there's 2 issues with that.

Comment: 1. The old front end db allows me to edit data (Even though it's linked to the new backend db.

Comment: Nope, i was wrong it was pointing to the backup version, so it must be something i did to the table

Comment: But the thing is, the Members table (the subform) is not changed in any way!